# Refresh only part of the page and change the URL? jQuery? Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page (http://myflashpics.com/picture/p9e0) with some user information in the side and small thumbnail in the side. What it's doing now is linking to a whole different page and the sidebar reloads as well. I was wondering if it was possible to change the image, comments section, the caption, as well the URL so if the user wants to link to it anywhere.

This might not be possible - but if it is I don't even know where to begin Googling this or even starting to comprehend how this will work.

All answers are appreciated! Links and source code would be nice too.

Comment: Sure... Never really worked with it so I have no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In browsers that support HTML5, you can use `window.history.pushState` to perform AJAX partial loading of pages and still completely change the URL of the page. This is what GitHub uses (see some more info as well as a video demonstrating the technique at [their blog post, *The Tree Slider*](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)). There is some great info on the subject on the [Dive Into HTML5 History API page](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

On browsers that don't support HTML5, you either *must* use `location.hash` (if you want linkable URLs) or else don't use AJAX (and stick with your current implementation). I am in the camp that [uses jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768573/refresh-only-part-of-the-page-and-change-the-url-jquery-is-this-possible/5768596#5768596) for this task.

Comment: See [the History.js project](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) for a library that supports `pushState` and still degrades gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like a situation for

- [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/)
- [jQuery.ajax() – jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: When in doubt (if javascript is involved) jQuery it out!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't change the URL without reloading the page *but* you can use AJAX to load new data ad if the page had changed. You can also track history by changing anything after the "#" in the address bar. A good example of a site that implements this is grooveshark.com

Comment: Instead of using something like this: http://mydomain.com/picture/randomstring for pictures, should I transform it to something like this is mod_rewrite: http://mydomain.com/picture/#/short string so it will work with location.hash?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using ajax. If you need to change the urls change the `location.hash` property using Javascript.

Comment: Wouldn't that be like http://mydomain.com/picture/oldstring#newstring? I want it to work like this: http://mydomain.com/picture/newstring

Comment: You will need to go for HTML5 in case don't like refreshing. . Else  you need to change `location.href` property which will refresh the page. Check history.js jQuery plugin, which will be the optimal solution.